# How do I build and launch a URL from user input?

Tags: javascript, batch-file, html

Okay so programmed a very simple batch file:

```
@echo off
set input=
set /P input=Enter Number Code: %=% 
start http://myanimelist.net/anime/%input%
```

This will take them to the website with the code number they enter.

For example, I enter: 111

It goes to http://myanimelist.net/anime/111

How can this same thing be done in PHP, JavaScript, HTML basically through a webpage?

Where it asks to enter a number code then sends them to the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trivially simple using JavaScript, I'd even suggest jQuery...

Your web page (html file) needs a text input field where the user can type the code:

```
<label for="numberInput">Enter Number Code:</label><input type="text" id="numberInput" />
<input type="button" value="Enter" id="enter"/>
```

​Then you attach a javascript event to the button that builds the URL and goes to it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#enter").click(function() {
        window.location = "http://myanimelist.net/anime/" + $("#numberInput").val();
    });                          

});​
```

Here's a working fiddle including markup.

http://jsfiddle.net/czX7R/1/

Answer (score 2):

In javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
code = prompt("Enter your desired code");
if (code != null && code != '') {
   window.location.href = 'http://myanimelist.net/anime/'+code;
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks both are great answers i chose jeff because his doesn't have a prompt box thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Nelson got there first as I was prannying around in jsFiddle :P

Comment: It's fine accepting Jeff's solution, more polished, also he needs the points more.